# How to set up facebook callback url?

Tags: facebook, canvas, unity-game-engine, payment

How do I setup a Canvas payments callback url?  I only need to set up for static pricing at this time within my app.  Facebook requires a Payments Object under "Realtime Updates" heading.  I have been searching everywhere for a simple straight example on how to do the complete process but have not been able to find one.  I have been working through the Unity3d Friendsmash example project.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found much information on the callback, but since I don't really use it, I just used this code inside a PHP script to just make it work:

```
$hub_mode = $_GET['hub_mode'];
$hub_challenge = $_GET['hub_challenge'];
$hub_verify_token = $_GET['hub_verify_token'];
if ($hub_verify_token =='YourToken')
{
    echo $hub_challenge;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out.  I put a php script into the Test Callback url and this is what I got back:   The request sent to your callback URL failed with the following error: 
Response does not match challenge, expected value = '2018397018', received='<?php ...'     FYI I am using Parse as my server backend.

Comment: I created a script with the above as content, and referenced it from the facebook developer page. Then put in a test token, and it worked. Game is live now, with payments working.

Don't know if you are doing something wrong, or Parse is different

Comment: I put the page into the Facebook debug tool and got back "Object at URL 'https://mysite.parseapp.com/callback.php' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.  Any ideas what this might be?  I am new to the webpage coding stuff(php, html,etc) so again I appreciate you helping me out.

Comment: You can't debug it from there, since its a debugging tool for Open Graph Objects, and this is a simple php script

Comment: My exact php script is looks like:   <?php                                    
$hub_mode = $_GET['hub_mode'];

$hub_challenge = $_GET['hub_challenge'];

$hub_verify_token = $_GET['hub_verify_token'];

if ($hub_verify_token =='YourToken')

{

echo $hub_challenge;

}
?>  Is this the right way to code the whole page?  TIn the "Test Callback URL" box on the Facebook Canvas Payments page I am entering https://mysite.parseapp.com/callbackStackOver.php  Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I've just used this code and it works fine. On your Facebook app page, you will have to fill out the URL where you are hosting this page, and fill out 'YourToken' in the other field. Or invent a meaningful token, change it in the code, and use THAT token

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!  I was using Parse which does not host php pages.  I put my file on my bluehost account and it now works!  My app can now show the pay dialog on Facebook using the callback url I gave it.