# Facebook Graph API User object subscriptions Whitelisting

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

in my iPhone app, I implemented the Facebook API, to piggy back on their user identification.

Now, rather than polling Facebook every once in a while to see if the information of a logged in user has changed, I would like to use the 'User object subscriptions'. From [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2) document I learned, that I have to create a Callback URL ([done, and tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110277/how-to-set-up-facebook-callback-url)), and that my app needs to be Whitelisted.

On developers.facebook.com/apps/ I can't find a way to apply for being whitelisted, and Google doesn't seem to be my friend anymore.

I hope *you* are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are stating

> ...some of these objects **may** require your app to be whitelisted by Facebook for access.

Basic Realtime Updates should work without any whitelisting involved, at least they do so for myself.

Comment: But how does my app find out about the fact that something has changed?  Is the a flag that it needs to check? I realize that this is another question

Comment: Well, I thought you have set up a callback url as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2#setup Read the docs again. FB will call your Callback URL via a POST request for every change. You need to publish your app's subscription as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions#publish as well.

Comment: Well, then my problem is, that I cannot find the place to put my callback URL. The only place I can find is related to the the Ads Object, which I'm not interested in.

Comment: Look at the docs! It's in the second link I posted in my last comment!

Comment: I am going crazy. I have been staring at the interface for hours now, but really, there is no sign of the user Graph API objects. That is why I assumed that I need to be white listed. Or maybe I'm just blind. Could you, in a way you would to a 4-year old child, explain to me, what buttons I should click after having logged in to developers.facebook.com/apps/ and having clicked on my app?

Comment: You have to manually trigger the subscription as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions#publish with a `POST /v2.2/{app-id}/subscriptions` with the appropirate configuration in the body. This has nothing to do with the app's configuration itself at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/!

Comment: Oh, I'm not crazy......I'm stupid! I hope this thread is helpful to other idiots as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, my brains started to work. I still have to technically make it work

Answer (score -1):

Whitelisting your app is not always easy to do, as certain APIs are meant to be quite restricted at a developer level. You can find further information about whitelisting [here](https://developers.facebook.com/marketingpartners) if you have not already done so.

As far as whitelisting, in your case I believe it just a matter of your app settings and IP whitelisting, which you can find more information about  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security) .

Comment: Hi Elizion, your first link seems to be a dead-end link, and the form you are referring to is to apply for an "Facebook Ads API Standard Access Application", which is not something that I'm interested in.